Python и Websocket
Всех приветствую, есть задача написать приложение
Клиентская часть - браузер - ползунки кнопочки (в частности интересует ползунки(input range)
Серверная часть - Python
Главный вопрос в том, как подружить HTML input range(событие ondrag) с сервером через Websocket
UPD:
моя задача такова - условно на клиентской части в браузере есть ползунок(input range), каждый раз меняя значение этого ползунка клиентская часть общается с сервером и обменивается данными, т.е. сервер выполняет команду ориентируясь на значение того самого ползунка

Что значит "подружить" и в чём проблема у вас?

И при чём здесь Java?  Вам скорее нужен JavaScript.

Уточните, пожалуйста, на каком этапе у вас проблема и в чём заключается сложность с её [проблема] решением

Прошу прощения действительно нужен js, моя задача такова - условно на клиентской части в браузере есть ползунок(input range), каждый раз меняя значение этого ползунка клиентская часть общается с сервером и обменивается данными, т.е. сервер выполняет команду ориентируясь на значение того самого ползунка


Главный вопрос в том, как подружить HTML input range(событие ondrag) с сервером через Websocket

Вот пример как можно обрабатывать событие input range. Так же показано место, где можно организовать отправку значения...


document.querySelector('[type="range"]').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const v = e.target.value
  // можно отправлять значение на сервер
  console.log(v)
})
<input type='range' min='0' max='100' step='1' value='0' />




А как соединить это с Websocket’Ом и как это перехватить на Python, какой фреймворк подойдет?

@Alexdebil, так ты почитай как работать с ВС на клиенте. https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets Про работу в Питоне расскажут питонисты.
